# I stumbled on the word "OKing" while reading an article. Is such Inflection of OK prevalent?

Tags: abbreviations, colloquialisms, email

Three of the primary dictionaries–the OED, M-W, and the Australian Concise Oxford (OA)–show OK as the preferred spelling and **okay** as an acceptable alternative.

The Chicago Manual of Style does not include a **rule** in any of its numbered sections **for** spelling or **inflecting OK**, but it does use the spelling OK in some of its examples.

Is the use of OKing acceptable?

Comment: Acceptable to whom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hear it a lot in conversation (in the USA). For example, forms I fill out may have to go to a manager to "get his OK". So it would not be at all unheard of for someone to ask me if said manager "has OKed" the paperwork. The act of doing so could certainly be called "OKing" the paperwork.

Since I mostly hear it in conversation, the issue of how that is spelled has never come up. I would think the spellings I've used above would suffice. However, probably **most folks would dodge the issue** by using a more formal verb form in writing, such as "authorize", or "approve". That would be my advice to you, if the issue of writing it ever comes up.

Comment: It's also common and well-understood business jargon in the UK, fwiw.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ok) has a verb form of *OK*, and lists *OK'd* and *OK'ing* as inflections. I think it's common to use a apostrophe when inflecting initialism.

Other dictionaries have similar entries.

Comment: +1 [*Oxford*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ok#OK) agrees about OK'ing.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry. From an earlier question.